# Remove custom taxonomy base slug from archive permalink

Tags: wordpress, permalinks, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I'm looking for a rewrite rule to remove the base taxonomy slug (topic) from a WordPress taxonomy archive permalink.

An example of the functionality I'm looking for is as follow:

`http://website.com/topic/health` would remove the `/topic` base slug and become
`http://website.com/health/`

I'm sure this is possible with [rewrite rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule), but what would that rewrite look like?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to remove things from your URL (which works) and then start wondering that removing parts from a URL make a different URL?

Comment: I've removed that code sample to simplify the question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was confused - now is Darren Cooney faster than me (he is right).

Answer (score 2):

When registering your custom taxonomy either remove the `rewrite` argument or set it to `false`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'namespace_register_taxonomy' );    
/**
 * Register a private 'Topic' taxonomy for post type 'Post'.
 */
function namespace_register_taxonomy() {
    $args = [
        'label'.  => __( 'Genre', 'textdomain' ),
        'public'  => true,
        'rewrite' => false,
    ];
    register_taxonomy( 'topic', 'post', $args );
}
```

Using the [`{$permastructname}_rewrite_rules`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/permastructname_rewrite_rules/) filter you can modify the rewrite rules. Replace the taxonomy slug in two places to make it work for your taxonomy. Flush the rewrite rules to see it work.

```
add_filter( 'topic_rewrite_rules', 'namespace_topic_rewrite_rules' );
/**
 * Filters rewrite rules used for individual permastructs.
 *
 * @param string[] $rules Array of rewrite rules generated for the current permastruct, keyed by their regex pattern.
 * @return string[] Array of rewrite rules.
 */
public function namespace_topic_rewrite_rules( array $rules ): array {
    $terms = get_terms(
        [
            'taxonomy'   => 'topic',
            'hide_empty' => false,
        ]
    );
    $slugs         = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
    $slugs_pattern = '(' . implode( '|', array_unique( $slugs ) ) . ')';

    $new_rules = [];
    foreach ( $rules as $pattern => $query ) {
        $pattern               = str_replace( 'topic/([^/]+)', $slugs_pattern, $pattern );
        $new_rules[ $pattern ] = $query;
    }
    return $new_rules;
}
```

Now that the archive page is working, the link to the term archive page needs to be modified.

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'namespace_topic_term_link', 10, 3 );
/**
 * Remove base from Topic taxonomy term link.
 *
 * @param string   $termlink Term link URL.
 * @param \WP_Term $term     Term object.
 * @param string   $taxonomy Taxonomy slug.
 * @return string Term link URL.
 */
public function namespace_topic_term_link( string $termlink, \WP_Term $term, string $taxonomy ): string {
    if ( 'topic' === $taxonomy ) {
        $termlink = str_replace( 'topic/', '', $termlink );
    }
    return $termlink;
}
```

Comment: `//$slugs         = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'slug' );
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        $parent = ($term->parent > 0) ? $parent = get_term_by("term_id", $term->parent, "topic") : false;
        $slugs[] = (((!is_wp_error($parent)) && ($parent)) ? $parent->slug . "/" : "") . $term->slug;
    }
`

Comment: That's a little fix I added to make **namespace_topic_rewrite_rules** work with subcategories, (I needed for just one level this time)

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will help you:

```
function custom_topic_link( $link, $term, $taxonomy )
{
    if ( $taxonomy !== 'topic' )
        return $link;

    return str_replace( 'topic/', '', $link );
 }
add_filter( 'term_link', 'custom_topic_link', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks. That updates the tax archive link, but the not the rewrite. That link returns 404 (permalinks flushed).

Comment: set permalink structure from admin to '/%postname%/'